# Matrix not getting a value in some positions

Tags: c++

The excercise requires me to make a matrix where the user chooses the size of the matrix. The matrix is filled with random numbers and then displayed on screen. For some reason the fourth slot is 0 every time no matter what the size of the matrix is.

```
int main () {
int matriz[100][100] , filas , columnas ;

cout << "Ingrese el numero de filas: " ; cin >> filas ;
cout << "Ingrese el numero de columnas: " ; cin >> columnas ;

for (int i = 0 ; i < filas ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < columnas ; j++) {
        //srand(time(NULL)) ;
        matriz[i][j] = rand()%100 ;
    }
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < filas ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < columnas ; j++) {
        cout << matriz[i][j] << " " ;
    }
cout << endl ;
}
return 0 ; }
```

It is behaving how it is supposed to behave except on the fourth iteration of the  for statement

Example of an expected result on a 3*3 matrix:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

What I get when using this code:

1 2 3
0 5 6
7 8 9

Comment: rand() is not a really good way to generate a random number. Try seeding it

Comment: Can you provide your actual and expected output? Without seeding (as it is currently), it should be the same every time you run your program, with seeding every loop iteration it's quite likely that it will generate a series of identical numbers.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 When I google how to make random numbers rand() is the thing that comes up first. I'll look into how to do what you're telling me to do :)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I've edited the post with an expected output and the one I end up getting

Comment: The problem is, there is nothing wrong with this code. Matrix initialization has no matter since you've manually set value for all elements (as `rand()`) that you read later. The question is, how do you know what is expected value for `rand() % 100`, given it is random? (Obligatory Dilbert: https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25 )

Comment: For reference, `integer % 100` returns value in range [0-99] inclusive.

Comment: @R2RT The expected values are an example (i don't pretend to get those numbers exactly). I ran it many times and the 0 allways comes up in the same place no matter the size of the matrix. I know random means you can get the 0 in the same spot every single time but it's a bit unlikely to come up more than 10 times in a row on the same spot

Comment: It's unlikely, assuming that `rand()` is indeed good RNG, that your seed does change between runs. There is chance that implemetation of `rand()` on your system returns 0 on its 4th call and there is nothing you can do about it. Except of switching to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random Anyway, my point is, you could try to fill matrix with deterministic values like `i + 100*j` and check whenever your title problem has anything to do with initialization or `for` loops. If it does not, only thing that is left as problematic is `rand()`.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're declaring an `int[][]` but not initializing it.

`matriz[100][100]` is declared but never initialized, by calling `int matriz[100][100]{}` you directly initialize it.

Comment: There's no UB, all elements that are read are set first (provided that `filas` and `columnas` are both less than `100`)

Comment: This answer is not remotely correct. Declaring an array creates an array of objects, but the values are not set. It is UB to read the values, but it's completely fine to set the values.

Comment: Of course there is memory allocated, on the stack. It's a variable with automatic storage duration.

Comment: @Amachi It is stack memory, memory is allocated -- it's just not _initialized_. There is a huge difference. This answer is blatantly wrong. The array should be initialized to prevent a bad read, but that's where the correctness of this answer ends.

Comment: @Amachi Thanks! That fixed it! 
I also fixed it by creating another int variable, assigning the random value to it and then using it to give the value to every position (not sure why that worked) but I like more this way of doing it and from now on I'll start keeping in mind that I have to initialize the matrixes when using them.